# jQuery add 2 values only if radio is checked

Tags: jquery

I have a long list of variables that depending on what is selected change the total price. I am trying to take an existing variable, and add the value of a radio button to it, but only if the radio button is selected. I have this working, but when I change the radio button selected it continues adding to the existing number. I need to be able to change which radio button is selected, and it remove the previously added number and add the value of the newly selected one. Is this possible, or am I going to have to rethink this one?

```
 $('.pestOptions').click(function () {
     var selection = $('.pestOptions:checked').val();
     var programCost = $('.programCostPestControl').text();
     var pestTotalFinal = parseFloat(selection) + parseFloat(programCost);
     if(isNaN(pestTotalFinal)) {
            $('.programCost').html('Call For Pricing');
     }  
     $('.programCostPestControl').text(pestTotalFinal.toFixed(2));
 });
```

Comment: is pestOptions the radio button?

Comment: My apologies. Yes, it is.

Comment: Did you tried

$(".pestOptions:checked")
instead of

$('.pestOptions.selected')
?

.selected does not work for me. But :checked works like a charm.

Comment: Add your html code here, and maybe don't use the variable name 'checked'

Comment: I stripped out most of the unneeded code, and narrowed it down to only the "pest control" variables. When I select a radio option, it replaces the value instead of adding. I'm not seeing any reason why...Am I missing something? Here is the jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/p89n079r/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change where things are set, and a couple other things. Here's a working sample:

```
// Set this value outside of the radio button change handler, 
// so its more like in the global scope
var programCost = $('.programCostPestControl').val();  

// set the handler for the radio button change event
$('input[name="rbg"]').change(function () {
     var checkedVal = $('input[name="rbg"]:checked').val();
     // `programCost` is already set outside of this function, 
     //  so it doesn't change -- only gets added to 
     var pestTotalFinal = parseFloat(checkedVal) + parseFloat(programCost);

     if(isNaN(pestTotalFinal)) {
            $('.programCost').html('Call For Pricing');
     }  

     $('.programCostPestControl').val(pestTotalFinal.toFixed(2));
 });
```

(For this HTML)

```
<label>Add 2 <input class="pestOptions" type="radio" name="rbg" value="2"/></label><br/>
<label>Add 4 <input class="pestOptions" type="radio" name="rbg" value="4"/></label><br/>
<input class="programCostPestControl" type="text" value="12"/>
```

[**See it in action here**](http://jsfiddle.net/do1feve1/)

Comment: Thank you very much! This works for what I need, for some reason when I implement this in my code it doesn't work right. It replaces the total number with the value of the radio button. There must be something of mine further up the page interfering I guess. Great answer though.

Comment: I stripped out most of the unneeded code, and narrowed it down to only the "pest control" variables. When I select a radio option, it replaces the value instead of adding. I'm not seeing any reason why...Am I missing something? Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p89n079r/8/

Comment: ohmygod. let me adjust that for you.

Comment: @cameron Here, take a [look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p89n079r/13/), and if that works for you, accept my answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much and sorry. That was killing me. Thanks again!